# Leaflet Multipolygon custom popup

Tags: popup, leaflet, geojson

I have an OSM map and I'm using leafletjs.

I have created my custom popup for marker. It it works fine and correctly.

```
marker.bindPopup(strMsg,{className: 'myPopup'});
```

This code works perfectly.

Now, I want to create a the same popup, but clicking on Multilopygon. The data for the polygon comes from geoJSON. This is the code I wrote for this issue

```
var c_park = L.geoJson(data[i].geom, {
            style: myStyle
            });
           c_park.bindPopup("strMsg",{className: 'myPopup'});
           map.addLayer(c_park);
```

The problem is myPopup class is not working for the popup of multipolygon and as a result I get the native popup window. If I manually change the class in browser - it is ok.

I tried different methods. F.e. using function onEachFeature to init popups. But nothing works.

Does anybody knows what is the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does anybody knows what is the problem ?

There is no problem. ClassName is supported for markers as an option of L.icon. ([docs](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker)).

Polygon inherits the options of polyline and path, which do not include ClassName ([docs](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#polygon)).

The way I see it you have two possibilities:

1. fork leaflet and add the className option to polygon
2. make a subclass inheriting polygon taking className as an option by overloading bindPopup

Comment: Thanks. I solved my issue by overloading css classes inside leaflet.css

Comment: That's a good idea! (I think I'm going to use it in my project :) )